# How to send large files though PHP without POST with server limit

Tags: php, post, ftp, limit, filesize

we have a server with a limit on POST file size (64MB) and we can't change that, is there a way to upload larger files through PHP to work around this? Or another method aside from using and FTP client?

Thanks

Comment: Maybe you can make the remote side fetch the file instead of pushing it there?

Comment: have you looked into http PUT verb ? problem is not all browsers supports it .

Answer (score 4):

Unless you have the ability to change PHP settings on the server (have you tried htaccess?), you'll need to use a program on the client-end (Java, possibly Flash), that splits the file up into chunks and uploads each one individually. Your server combines the chunks to "re-create" the file after they are all uploaded.

Answer (score 0):

`ini_set()`, a `php.ini` in script dir, `.htaccess` - neither of these don't work? What I mean is maybe you don't need to complicate things so much with that flash on client side, and maybe you'll can go other ways.

Comment: `we have a server with a limit on POST file size (64MB) and we can't change that`...

Comment: I get it. But did you tried all of this 3? I'm not pretending that it would work for sure, but you can give a try. Putting a `php.ini` file in the same dir with the php file you're executing, can work.

Answer (score 0):

HTTP isn't meant for transferring really large files. You should look into employing a different protocol.

Answer (score 0):

You can send the data using the PUT method. `post_max_size` doesn't affect those requests.